How do I permanently hide __pycache__ directories from Finder?
I've tried a few different variations on this command:
find . -name "__pycache__" -exec chflags hidden {} +
It works and I no longer see these directories in my Finder. But then at some point (maybe after a reboot?) they come back.
Can someone tell me what triggers these directories to come back and how I might permanently hide them?

They come back because you're setting an attribute on a specific file, not a class of file.  The file gets recreated, not re-written with new data, and so the attribute is gone.

An alternative solution might be to move those directories to somewhere where they’re out of the way.

didn't read through that whole issue. is this implemented?
